# How to send an Json in GET method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

Hi I'm trying to translate a code in python to Javasrcipt.

```
import requests
url = "myApi"
r = requests.get(url, json = {"from": "default", "to": "default"})
dic = r.json()
```

I don't know how to do it in Javascript. Please help me!!!!

Comment: [HTTP GET requests can't have a json body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)

Comment: Use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: [This may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const url = "myApi";

fetch(`${url}?${new URLSearchParams({
    from: "default",
    to: "default",
})}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(result => console.log('myApi response', result))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use XMLHttpRequest :

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = "url?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"from": "default", "to": "default"}));
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.from + ", " + json.to);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```